# Is there any way to integrate javadoc into TestNG reports

Tags: java, javadoc, testng

Could someone please let me know whether there is a way to integrate the javadoc of a test method into TestNG reports?

I have googled this topic and searched around here as well, but not much useful info so far.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In other words you want to:

1. "extract the javadoc entries programmatically" and
2. use them in the report.

Googling for 1. yielded http://eubauer.de/kingsware/2010/12/19/access-javadoc-programmatically/

and 2. is, uhm, simple, use TestNG [Reporter](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/Reporter.html).

Also, you might prefer `description` parameter to `@Test` annotation, this would save you from implementing the 1. part but this might be not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I'll have to try it out.